# No more messing up whitespace in VIM

Tags: linux, editor, vim

I have an `BufWritePre` hook added to my `.vimrc` that trims trailing whitespace before a buffer is saved. This is very convenient for me when editing my own code or that of others who also have a policy to always remove trailing whitespace. However, this makes me sometimes mess up the whitespace of others, which doesn't look very nice in version control.

I have two ideas how this could be solved in general, both of which I have specific problems with:

#### Option 1

After opening a file (maybe using a `BufReadPost` hook), detect whether there is trailing whitespace in the file. If yes, set a buffer-local flag to signal this. If the flag is set, disable the trimming before a save.

The problem I have with this approach is that I don't seem to figure out **how I can detect whether there is trailing whitespace** in the buffer. I know about `=~`, but how do I get the buffer contents as a string? Or even better, I can do a search using `/\s+$<cr>`, but how can I check if the search was successful (if there are hits)?

#### Option 2 (more intelligent)

It would be even better if the whitespace trimming would only happen on the lines that were actually modified. This way I could have the benefit of not having to care about trailing whitespace in my code but still not messing up the rest of the file. This raises the question: **can I somehow get the line numbers of the lines I added or modified?**

I'm new to Vimscript, so I'd appreciate any hints or tips :)

**UPDATE:** I settled with option 1 now:

```
" configure list facility
highlight SpecialKey term=standout ctermbg=yellow guibg=yellow
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~

" determine whether the current file has trailing whitespace
function! SetWhitespaceMode()
  let b:has_trailing_whitespace=!!search('\v\s+$', 'cwn')
  if b:has_trailing_whitespace
    " if yes, we want to enable list for this file
    set list
  else
    set nolist
  endif
endfunction

" trim trailing whitespace in the current file
function! RTrim()
  %s/\v\s+$//e
  noh
endfunction

" trim trailing whitespace in the given range
function! RTrimRange() range
  exec a:firstline.",".a:lastline."substitute /\\v\\s+$//e"
endfunction

" after opening and saving files, check the whitespace mode
autocmd BufReadPost  * call SetWhitespaceMode()
autocmd BufWritePost * call SetWhitespaceMode()
" on save, remove trailing whitespace if there was already trailing whitespace
" in the file before
autocmd BufWritePre  * if !b:has_trailing_whitespace | call RTrim() | endif

" strip whitespace manually
nmap <silent> <leader>W :call RTrim()<cr>
vmap <silent> <leader>W :call RTrimRange()<cr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 can benefit from `search()` function, like so:

```
let b:has_trailing_spaces=!!search('\v\s+$', 'cwn')
```

`search()` function returns a number of matched line (they start from 1) or 0 if nothing was found, `!!` turns it to either 1 or 0, dropping information about on which line `search()` found trailing whitespace. Without `n` flag `search()` moves the cursor which is, I guess, undesired. Without `w` it may search only in the part of buffer that is after the cursor (really depends on `'wrapscan'` option).

Proposed option 2 implementation is a hack that uses `InsertLeave` and `'[`, `']` markers:

```
augroup CleanInsertedTrailingSpaces
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertLeave * let wv=winsaveview() | keepjumps lockmarks '[,']s/\s\+$//e | call winrestview(wv)
augroup END
```

It assumes that you only add trailing whitespaces after typing. It will break if you move your cursor across the lines in insert mode. You can also try adding

```
    autocmd CursorHold * if getpos("'.")[1]!=0 | let wv=winsaveview() | keepjumps lockmarks '.s/\s\+$//e | call winrestview(wv) | endif
```

, this should remove trailing spaces at the line of last change (only one line, `'[` and `']` can’t be used here because they point to first and last lines to often to be useful). Both autocommands should add information to undo tree.

There is a second option for the option 2: `git annotate` is able to annotate current state of the file thus you can use `grep` to filter out lines that have both trailing spaces and uncommitted changes and use a hook to purge unwanted spaces from them before commit. Sad, but `hg annotate` is not able to do so and thus you will have to write something more complex, possibly in python. I can’t say anything about other VC systems.

I guess it would be better if you used `set list listchars+=trail:-` to see such spaces and thus be able to remove them manually if they accidentally appear (personally I can’t remember myself constantly adding trailing spaces by accident, though in comments and documentation they are used by me intentionally to indicate that paragraph continues). What do you do so that this problem appears?

Comment: Your solution for option 1 seems fine, thank you very much. I think this will be sufficient for the time being. As for option 2, your information also seems to be handy, maybe I can hack something together with that. I don't usually move my cursor around in insert mode (and I think this is part of the VIM philosophy). As for motivation: I've seen many open source projects with a very inconsistent usage of trailing whitespace. Sometimes it is removed completely from a file, sometimes only parts of files have trailing whitespace, etc...

Comment: I don't want to care about whitespace while coding, I think this it's a task of the editor to handle that. But I also don't want to commit superflous whitespace changes (especially if like you said, it actually has a meaning). I will accept this answer, but first I want to wait a little bit to see if someone else has any thoughts on this, at least if you don't mind.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark Haven’t you thought about using git hooks for option 2 (more information in last but one paragraph I added a few minutes ago)? I personally prefer mercurial, but with git *this* job is done simpler.

Comment: ZyX: Git hooks are definitely an option that I use for my own projects, but I don't want this to be dependent on version control.

Answer (score 3):

I tend not to let vim automatically trim anything. As you say, this can be a nightmare if dealing with other peoples code, and can lead to unnecessary conflicts. The approach I take, to keep my own code tidy is to make whitespace visible. With vim this can be achieved by adding the following to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=DarkGray
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~
set list
```

The result is to show whitespace like this:

[image: vim show whitespace]

This allows me to keep files clean whilst I write them. Most other (GUI) editors have the ability to show whitespace too.

Comment: I think this is mostly a matter of taste. In my opinion handling whitespace is a task that can actually be performed by the editor, thus saving me some unnecessary edits. I know about listchars and have it enabled, but I don't like editing whitespace.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Some would say this is not a matter of taste, but doing this automagically will mess up your commit history by mixing style changes with other changes. This might be against policy in some environments.

Comment: @honk: That's exactly my problem. I want VIM to handle this automatically for *my own* code, but not mess with the rest of the code. The effect of this is that there will be no whitespace-related changes in my commits.

Answer (score 2):

```
" Show trailing whitepace and spaces before a tab:
:highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
:match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
:autocmd ColorScheme * highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
```

This way any bad whitespace will glow in red. It's quite hard to miss.

Comment: I can have that easier with listchars, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Sorry about that. I just wanted to show another method. This way you can keep list for other purposes. You don't need automatic trimming if you don't put any unwanted whitespace in your code in the first place. And believe me, if you set it to a highly visible color You will automaticly correct yourself, and learn to avoid it pretty fast. ;)

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for your additional thoughts on this :)